# simple linq needed

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of Linq objects of type **Link** that contains values as following:

```
new Link {SourceId = 1, TargetId=22223}
new Link {SourceId = 1, TargetId=2221223}
new Link {SourceId = 1, TargetId=222}
new Link {SourceId = 2, TargetId=26556}
new Link {SourceId = 2, TargetId=264}
new Link {SourceId = 2, TargetId=262}
new Link {SourceId = 2, TargetId=29}

class Link
{
    public int SourceId { get; set; }
    public int TargetId { get; set; }
}
```

I need a LINQ statement to output a dictionary `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` that contains following:

the distinct `SourceId` as key and List of `TargetId` associated with that key as the value.

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this has anything to do with LINQ?

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester - Are you sure it's homework?

Comment: @HenkHolterman The sentence that was still there before your edit looked very much copied from a homework assignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var dic = links.GroupBy(x=>x.SourceID)
               .ToDictionary(x=> x.Key, x => x.Select(y=>y.TargetId).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<int, int> dict = links.ToDictionary(item => 
                                               item.SourceId ,
                                               item => item.TargetId)
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: This might fail when you try to insert duplicated keys to the Dictionary, wouldn't it? Missing GroupBy?

Comment: There is more than one item for each key, ToDictionary won't work, but ToLookup would have worked (it wouldn't return a Dictionary of Lists though)